# In R Shiny, how to use conditional if/then in lieu of the "req" or required input function in response to an Action Button?

Tags: r, shiny

In the below working example code, in the `renderUI` section towards the bottom of the `server` section, a `req` function is used to run a single course of action in response to user clicking the action button. (I think the defined functions occupying about the top half of code can be ignored for addressing the question at hand.)

My question is, very specifically, how do I replace `req` with an if/then conditional statement, with 2 differing courses of action depending on whether or not the user has clicked the button? So for example, if the user has not clicked the button yet, then in that sidebar panel a string of text appears such as "Awaiting input", and if the user clicks the button, then "Awaiting input" disappears and a matrix pops up, as currently working?

I know there are other ways to get that default "Awaiting input" to appear at inception, but I need to know how to replace `req` with if/then in order to solve an analogous problem I have.

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y  
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA              
  b <- c(1,b)                
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)
  a[Y] <- Z
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:X)
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                       sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                       matrix1.input("base_input"),
                       useShinyjs(),
                       actionButton('showBtn','Show vector'), 
                       actionButton('hideBtn','Hide vector'),
                       uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,plotOutput("graph1")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vector.final(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input())),type="b"))
 }) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this -

```
output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    if(input$showBtn == 0)
      h3('Awaiting input')
    else 
      tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, that works! And I was able to use your solution in the larger App that the above code derives from. I was uncertain of where if/then statements work. Seems they work almost anywhere.